# TS Compiler API: How do I get type of 'unknown' from TypeScript's TypeChecker?

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

TypeScript's TypeChecker API has functions like `getAnyType` and `getUndefinedType`, but there appears to be no `getUnknownType`. How do I get `unknown` as a `Type` to use for equality checks?

I've used `typeToString` to convert `Type` to `unknown` for equality checks in other cases, but for this case I need the `Type` version of `unknown` and can't figure out any viable workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at checker.ts, the unknown type:

```
var unknownType = createIntrinsicType(TypeFlags.Unknown, "unknown");
```

...is not exposed. I would recommend opening a PR in TypeScript's repo to add it to `TypeChecker`, as I believe they would accept it given the other methods found on there.

In the meantime, you can hackily get it by doing the following:

```
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile("file.ts", "type Unknown = unknown", ts.ScriptTarget.ESNext, true);
const unknownType = checker.getTypeFromTypeNode(sourceFile.statements[0].type);
```

Answer (score 0):

I posed the question incorrectly. I should have asked: "How can I confirm a `Type` is of type `unknown`?"

After consulting with the TypeScript team, the TS Compiler may have multiple definitions for intrinsic types internally, making the various `get<Type>` accessors inherently unstable.

The canonical way to check for intrinsic types like `undefined` and `unknown` is to compare `Type.flags` to `TypeFlags.Undefined` and `TypeFlags.Unknown`.

Comment: "the TS Compiler may have multiple definitions for intrinsic types internally" I don't think that's currently true, but yeah it's better to compare `TypeFlags`. That's what ts-morph does ([see here](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/blob/930779a0d3699be35ab17bbe9dd26ec00350fe53/packages/ts-morph/src/compiler/types/Type.ts#L565))

Comment: Those are the Typescript's teams words, not mine. They assertively stated that the `get<Intrinsic>Type` accessors should not be used to compare types for this reason.